# Displaying validation errors from an input array in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am submitting an array of inputs to my controller like so:

```
<input id="box-1-nickname" name="box-nickname[]" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Required">
<input id="box-2-nickname" name="box-nickname[]" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Required">
```

I am doing some validation like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'supplies-count' => 'required|in:0,1,2,3,4',
    ));

$arrayValidator = Validator::make(Input::all(), []);

$arrayValidator->each('box-nickname', ['required|min:1|max:60']);

if( $validator->fails() || $arrayValidator->fails() ) {
    return Redirect::route('route-2')
           ->withErrors($arrayValidator)
           ->withInput();
}
```

The problem is when I try to check the errors like this it doesn't work:

```
if( $errors->has('box-1-nickname') ) { echo ' has-error'; }
```

Comment: what happens when you `dd($errors->all())`? Also, what is the point of your $arrayValidator?

Comment: @Victor if I add two `box`es with no `box-nickname` and submit I get this from `dd($errors->all())` http://laravel.io/bin/vBjXv

Comment: Looks like you want to add a class, but it will be difficult since you are passing an array as the input name. You may have to rename your inputs.

Comment: @DavidNguyen correct I am passing an array because `box` inputs can be added and removed dynamically on the front end so I don't know how many might be submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably long found a solution, but for anyone else who stumbles across this:

The validator uses array dot notation of the field array keys. For example `box-nickname[0]` becomes `box-nickname.0`

Therefore `if( $messages->has('box-nickname.0') ) { echo ' has-error'; }` should give you your desired result. However, you will need to dynamically generate the array key since as you've said, you won't know how many box-nicknames are being applied. I use this in my form view:

```
@if(!is_null(Input::old('box-nickname')))
    @foreach(Input::old('box-nickname') as $n => $box-nickname)
        @include('box-nickname-create-form-partial')
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Then create a partial view called "box-nickname-create-form-partial.blade.php" or whatever you want to call it with the form field, which might look something like this:

```
<div class="form-group {!! $errors->has('box-nickname.'.$n) ? ' has-error' : '' !!}">
    <input name="box-nickname[{{$n}}]" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Required">
</div>
```

I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 15):

#### Displaying input array errors in the view (L5.8 onwards)

To get the first validation error for an input array:

```
{{ $errors->first('input_array.*') }}
```

To check if there is an error within an input array:

```
@if($errors->has('input_array.*'))
    <h1>There is an error in your input array</h1>
    <ul>
       @foreach($errors->get('input_array.*') as $errors)
           @foreach($errors as $error)
               <li>{{ $error }}</li>
           @endforeach
       @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Other examples:

```
@error('input_array.*')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

#### From 5.8^ documentation

[Working with error messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages)

> If you are validating an array form field, you may retrieve all of the messages for each of the array elements using the * character:

```
foreach ($errors->get('attachments.*') as $message) {
    //
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The errors are collected by `name` property, not `id`, and Laravel's default MessageBag variable is `$messages`, not `$errors`:

```
if( $messages->has('box-nickname') ) { echo ' has-error'; }
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: Could be `'box-nickname[]'` instead, I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: I tried box `box-nickname` and `box-nickname[]` but no luck.

Comment: @JoshMountain This just occurred to me - try `$messages` instead of `$errors`: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#working-with-error-messages

Comment: `$messages` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`$errors` is correct, but you should be checking for `box-nickname`. As you can see you will run into the issue of not being able to identify what box is what because of the generic name. I think the easiest way to to give each input a unique name (eg. `box-1`, `box-2`)and do a for loop on the server side to retrieve inputs that start with `box-`.